# Open class Public member functions

Tags: swift

I have a Shapes module in Swift including Shape class. I just have opened a new playground and added this module into source file. Square class in playground can inherits Shape class in Shapes module. There is no problem ,but public methods in Shape class are overridden in theSquare class.

According to swift sources, only open member functions can be overridden when inheritance is performed.

Maybe this is very base question, so I am already sorry for asking it.

Here's a sample playground code, the behavior is the same when `Parent` and `Child` are defined in different modules:

```
open class Parent {
    public init()     { print("Parent init") }
    public func foo() { print("Parent foo") }
    open func bar()   { print("Parent bar") }
}

class Child: Parent {
    override init()     { print("Child init") }
    override func foo() { print("Child foo") }
    override func bar() { print("Child bar") }
}

let child = Child()
child.foo()
child.bar()
```

Outputs:

```
Child init
Parent init
Child foo
Child bar
```

Comment: What I said is only valid for constructors not member functions. public initializers can be overriden.

Comment: Grammar and spelling edits.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should include your tried code to your post.
2. "only open member functions can be overridden when inheritance is performed", I don't think [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html) says that. Here are the differences between open and public classes:

> Open access applies only to classes and class members, and it differs
>   from public access as follows:
>
> - Classes with public access, or any more restrictive access level, can be subclassed only within the module where they’re defined.
> - Class members with public access, or any more restrictive access level, can be overridden by subclasses only within the module where
>     they’re defined.
> - Open classes can be subclassed within the module where they’re defined, and within any module that imports the module where they’re
>     defined.
> - Open class members can be overridden by subclasses within the module where they’re defined, and within any module that imports the
>     module where they’re defined.

Comment: Rule #2 you stated from the docs clearly says that public members can only be overridden from within their definition module. This is kind of conflicting with rule #3, which is a bit evasive.